# Trying to re-design a website with unknown origins

Tags: html, wordpress, web

So this is going to be a kinda complicated, frustrating question.

SO I recently started working for a company doing a lil marketing/social media. One of the things they wanted me to update was their website (refresh the look and layout and update the design) I've never built a website (i mean I have a Wix portfolio but..) and have had little HTML experience, but I've taken a bunch of c++, python and other coding classes and also really like figuring out new things. Their IT  guy now works for another side of the company and is very weird about relinquishing the passwords for the various social media sites and whatnot. When I finally got the admin passwords for the website I realized that that only lets you change the words on the website or add new info. There is no layout/coding capabilities at all. He also gave me the FTP access and the username and password for that. He was very weird about me changing things (even though the CEO asked me to) and won't give a straight, comprehensible answer about the capabilities we have with this website! The original person who created the website is no longer here and they can't seem to find his contact info.

So my main question is, how do I use the FTP info? Do I simply just download an FTP client and login there???? Will it even be possible for me to access this websites infrastructure? I just kind of need a starting point on what I should be researching/trying to do. 
Sorry this was so long and feel free to ask questions because I bet I was a little confusing.

PS. I don't even know what host it was built with like Wordpress or ya kno

Comment: Can you simplify the question? It seems like your question is regarding FTP.

Comment: "Do I simply just download an FTP client and login there????" — Well … yes. Why didn't you just try that?

Comment: "Will it even be possible for me to access this websites infrastructure?" — We have no idea how the site is set up. We have no way of knowing.

Comment: Thank you. Just FYI, I'm not going to run blindly into the website code and mess things up. I was just trying to fully understand everything and the possible limitations we could have before I talked to this guy again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know where the website is hosted? Ask him for the hosting provider login. Once you have that, you will be able to see what sort of installation you have there, and to obtain the credentials you'll need to FTP in via Filezilla or a similar tool. If he doesn't give you the info, take it to your boss and have them apply pressure from above.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I will have to do that. I've been trying to log on to FileZilla with the info he provided and its just not working. A lil over my head but I will figure this out!! He keeps saying they might just have to hire a company to create a new website but if we already have one I don't understand why we can't gain access and just update it!

Comment: If they hire a company to create a new website, and no one can access the current website, you'll have an SEO nightmare on your hands. Couple more pointers that may help... Look up where the domain is registered here: http://www.whoishostingthis.com/ - and then contact the hosting company directly, they may be of assistance. Also, check the source code on your home page and look for specific keywords: WordPress will have plugins and themes that contain the name, Drupal may have a version meta tag and a very distinct robots.txt file, etc. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

He might have added you as an author or a user that's not an admin. Make sure your an admin.
The FTP can be accessed from the hosing service, but you mentioned that he didn't give you the details. So download Filezilla to access FTP.
Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for answering!! I have been trying to login with FileZilla with the info he has given me but it is not working. But I will just have to ask him!

Comment: No problem! If I was you I'd ask for the hosting login. You can access FTP, and that's where the info to log in on FileZilla is. Just know, to access FTP you need,1. The Host URL (usually ftp://websiteurl)2. The username for FTP (located in the hosting provider) 3. The password (also the hosting provider.)4. The Port (Hosting has this info too).

Comment: Ah ok I will do that! But I have the FTP username and password and was just using 21 as the port... I was a little confused what to put into Host for FileZilla but I tried all sorts of different things (including just the plain web URL). But nothing seemed to work. If I have the FTP info it should work on FileZilla regardless of how the site was created right? I was reading online and I'm thinking it could be the firewall but need to check on that

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. The ftp url is ftp://yourwebsiteurl